# Jenkins - Helm - Docker not found when try to run a test

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes-helm

Currently, I'm using Helm and Terraform to deploy my Jenkins on GCP. It is my terraform code:

```
variable "project_id" { default = "vision40-teste" }
variable "region" { default = "us-central1-a" }

variable "plugins" { default = [
  "kubernetes:1.12.0",
  "workflow-job:2.23",
  "workflow-aggregator:2.5",
  "credentials-binding:1.16",
  "git:3.9.1",
  "blueocean:1.7.1"
]}

provider "google" {
  version = "~> 1.0"
  region  = "${var.region}"
  project = "${var.project_id}"
}

resource "helm_release" "jenkins" {
  name      = "jenkins"
  chart     = "stable/jenkins"

  set {
    name  = "Master.AdminUser"
    value = "someuser"
  }

  set {
    name  = "Master.AdminPassword"
    value = "somepassword"
  }

  set {
    name = "Master.InstallPlugins"
    value = "{${join(",", var.plugins)}}"
  }

  set {
    name = "Agent.AlwaysPullImage"
    value = true
  }

  set {
    name = "Agent.Image"
    value = "adriagalin/jenkins-jnlp-slave"
  }

  set {
    name = "Agent.ImageTag"
    value = "latest"
  }
}
```

But when I try to run some docker command on pipeline I get this error:

> [vision_front_new_master-PTH4UDTQVSAS7VICPCO2UFHIE5M6B37LQYLEJT5BMAT36AYX77KA]
>   Running shell script
>
> - docker pull node:carbon
>
> /home/jenkins/workspace/vision_front_new_master-PTH4UDTQVSAS7VICPCO2UFHIE5M6B37LQYLEJT5BMAT36AYX77KA@tmp/durable-e821ca88/script.sh:
>   2:
>   /home/jenkins/workspace/vision_front_new_master-PTH4UDTQVSAS7VICPCO2UFHIE5M6B37LQYLEJT5BMAT36AYX77KA@tmp/durable-e821ca88/script.sh:
>   docker: not found
>
> script returned exit code 127

I tried to use other image for the agent but it stills not working.

Comment: You need an image with docker installed in it for your build agents. May I recommend `docker:stable`?

Comment: I think that this image that I'm using already have -> https://github.com/adriagalin/docker-jenkins-jnlp-slave

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I updated my values.yaml to use

```
Master:
  AdminUser: user
  AdminPassword: user
  InstallPlugins:
   - kubernetes:1.12.0
   - workflow-job:2.23
   - workflow-aggregator:2.5
   - credentials-binding:1.16
   - git:3.9.1
   - blueocean:1.7.1 
Agent:
  Image: adriagalin/jenkins-jnlp-slave
  ImageTag: 1.4
  AlwaysPullImage: true
  volumes:
   - type: HostPath
     volumeName: docker-sock
     hostPath: /var/run/docker.sock
     mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: I'm running the helm chart version of jenkins/stable on my macbook with Docker Desktop and the above was the only resource I found that was helpful in getting it working for building Docker images inside jenkins. I used the above settings but with no versions.  I also had to alter "Usage" for the master node in Jenkins/Settings to "only build jobs with label expressions" and set the Executors to 2.  If I can automate all this I'll do my own answer

Comment: @Vorsprung can you elaborate on what you did exactly? I found some hints here: https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/7002 but I'm not using pipelines and after exposing the sock, how to make sure the docker command can be called in the project (jenkins master)?